# juju cache to different folder

Tags: juju

I am writing a juju charm for a project and I would like to test and debug locally.

I have a somewhat small SSD drive which I have my OS installed on and my home folder on the larger non SSD drive.  Juju is caching a lot of stuff to the SSD drive and I would like to cache to the other drive.

I tried using a symlink

```
    ln -s ~/juju/cache /var/cache/lxc
```

But I still get an OS warning after a while saying I am running out of disk space.

Could someone help me get juju to cache somewhere where it will not fill my SSD drive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the command, you are now creating a sym link from `~/juju/cache` in to `/var/cache/lxc`.

Try `ln -s /var/cache/lxc ~/juju/cache` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the way you suggested but I am finding that it is still filling up.  If I go to /var/cache/lxc I can start to see files populating the directory.  I see the same thing when I go to ~/juju/cache  the same files.   Clearly I am doing something wrong.  And I get the warning about low HDD space again.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be cache, but the actual containers themselves. Installed fully, they'll each take 800MB - 1GB at least. So be mindful of that.

Also, the local provider enforces use of `apt-cacher-ng` for package downloads, so you may also have lots of debs in `/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng`

A useful command to figure out whats using all the space under a certain dir is:

```
du -m --max-depth=1 | sort -rn | head -10
```

That will give you the top 10 users of space (in MB) under the current directory.